# Getting date from convoluted text field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract the date/time from a text field that looks like this, into a date/time column:

some text - 29th Jul 2021 16:44

some different text - 2nd Jul 2021 12:31

Example code to reproduce:

```
select 'some text - 29th Jul 2021 16:44' 
union
select
'some different text - 2nd Jul 2021 12:31'
as textfield
```

This is a vendor supplied database I'm querying - there's no option to change the format.

I need to extract the date & time into a datetime field (the purpose is to do a comparison to a different date time field).

Is there any 'shortcuts' to doing this? I've began attempting lots of manual substring functions to extract individual parts to piece back together again, but its very cumbersome, and I feel like there must be a better way.

The dash (-) is always going to be in the same position (relative to the date aspects), which has been helpful, but I still feel like I'm going down the wrong approach.

Is there a way I can substring after the dash, and for SQL Server to recognise the format?

A challenge here is the 'day' aspect will be single digit for 1-9, but double digit for 10-31.

Comment: Nope... you're probably gonna have to do this the hard way, and there are probably going to be bugs and edge cases that take a while to work out.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? `TRY_PARSE` (available from 2016 onwards) can probably help some with this, by replacing suffixes like `th` and `nd` -- e.g. `SELECT TRY_PARSE('29 Jul 2021 16:44' AS DATETIME USING 'en-US')`.

Comment: You should also consider ditching SQL for this. DUmp the data into an application, use a "proper" programming language. Search features will not help anyway and SQL is chronically pathetic on programming. Also, on a "real" language it will be easier to do this as a good project which includes test cases. I did an address parser once, and this turned out to be WAY more complex than you think of - same may apply here with edge cases galore coming and haunting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like concise :

```
convert(datetime, stuff(right(txt, 19), 3, 2, ''), 106)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c8720885ef6239187b2c220d0dfa9ae2

This conversion relies on there being a space following the hyphen so that when picking up the rightmost 19 characters you'll either end up with a digit or a space character in the initial position. This then allows you to strip out the two characters of ordinal text from a known location. (I had initially put an `ltrim()` in before the conversion but the possibly leading space doesn't seem to break the conversion anyway.)

One advantage is that is avoids the potential of having other hyphens in the lead portion of the text interfering with the search. The whole issue of a marker/separator is eliminated completely.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data you can do this with a few uses of `replace` and a `substring`:

```
with t as (
    select 'some text - 29th Jul 2021 16:44' as textfield
    union
    select
    'some different text - 2nd Jul 2021 12:31'
)
select Try_parse(y.d as datetime using 'en-GB') as ExtractedDate
from t
cross apply(values(Substring(t.textfield, CharIndex('-',t.textfield)+2 ,100)))x(v)
cross apply(values(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(x.v,'st',''),'nd',''),'rd',''),'th','')))y(d)
```